# Ensure the type is a list while executing against YAML using text/template package

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm using the `text/template` package to dynamically construct my k8s manifest and I was almost successful in creating it the required output.

Since the target type is YAML, I want to ensure, the generated type of `.ownerReferences` and `.secrets` are created as list types in YAML, i.e. with a leading `-` on each entry.

The output I'm expecting to achieve is

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: Foobar
  labels:
    app: Foobar
  ownerReferences:
  - uid: 123456789
    kind: FoobarOrchestrator
secrets:
- name: thisisasecret1
- name: thisisasecret2
```

But with the attempt I have below

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

const serviceAccountTemplate = `---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{.Name}}
{{- if .Labels}}
  labels:
{{- end }}
{{- range $key, $value := .Labels }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .OwnerRef}}
  ownerReferences:
{{- end }}
{{- range .OwnerRef }}
    uid: {{ .UID }}
    kind: {{ .Kind }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Secrets}}
secrets:
{{- end }}
{{- range $value := .Secrets }}
  name: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
`

func main() {
    type OwnerRef struct {
        UID  string
        Kind string
    }

    data := struct {
        Name     string
        Secrets  []string
        Labels   map[string]string
        OwnerRef []OwnerRef
    }{
        "dude",
        []string{"thisisasecret1", "thisisasecret2"},
        map[string]string{"app": "Foobar"},
        []OwnerRef{OwnerRef{UID: "123456789", Kind: "Foobar"}},
    }

    t := template.New("t")
    t, err := t.Parse(serviceAccountTemplate)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I was able to produce below

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dude
  labels:
    app: Foobar
  ownerReferences:
    uid: 123456789
    kind: Foobar
secrets:
  name: thisisasecret1
  name: thisisasecret2
```

but I want to be sure, if the types are accurate to be accepted by a proper YAML decoder.

Also would appreciate any enhancements to my existing template definition.

Playground link - https://go.dev/play/p/EbxcvGcYr9r

Comment: Am I missing something or what's the problem with simply adding `-` in front of the key like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/NDw0fLB-zkF)?

Comment: @mkopriva Yeah that’s an option yes. But does that guarantee with the YAML syntax of being encoded as a list type?

Comment: There's no support in `text/template` to check for proper YAML syntax. If you want guarantee you'll probably have to write tests. And if you'd like to feel more certain that the generated YAML is syntactically valid then you should probably ditch the template and instead use structs and a YAML encoder, like `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` for example.

Comment: However the specific example from the question seems to do fine when fed to the `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` decoder: https://go.dev/play/p/R86Feu5VZOK (I'm not sure if that's guarantee enough for you)

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva If you can surmise that to answer, I'll be happy to accept and move on,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the example template output YAML sequences for the desired nodes you can simply prepend `-` in front of the child nodes. E.g.

```golang
const serviceAccountTemplate = `
...
{{- if .OwnerRef}}
  ownerReferences:
{{- end }}
{{- range .OwnerRef }}
    - uid: {{ .UID }}
      kind: {{ .Kind }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Secrets}}
secrets:
{{- end }}
{{- range $value := .Secrets }}
  - name: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
`
```

https://go.dev/play/p/R86Feu5VZOK

---

There's however no support in `text/template` to check for proper YAML syntax. If you need guarantee that the generated text is valid YAML you'll have to write the tests for that.

But, just like when you want to generate JSON in Go you'd normally use structs and `encoding/json`, so too with YAML you can use structs and `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` to generate consistently valid YAML.